The object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor or the _valueTracker don't work. How to emulate the user input in the react form with multiple inputs?
I am creating a Chrome extension to auto-fill react forms. There is a form with multiple lines in the page. Each line has selection and input and can be deleted with a button.
I used the following two methods, but neither works. When I click another input or other button after I set the value, the injected input value disappears (gets lost again) right after user's one or two clicks - so frustrating!
Method #1:
function setReactInputValue(element, value) {
    const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value').set;
    nativeInputValueSetter.call(element, "xxx");
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
}

Method #2:
lastValue = input1.value;
let tracker = input1.\_valueTracker;
if(tracker) 
{ 
    tracker.setValue("xxx");
}

I guess that React renders the form when I click one time or two times. When I input the value by hand, the form worked correctly.
When I click some elements (buttons or inputs) in the form, why do the input values I injected with javascript get lost?
Can someone show the ultima method to change the form input values?
